# A question about tableau method for first-order logic

Tags: logic

I have a doubt about tableau method for f-o logic.

In Smullyan's book (*First-Order Logic*, 1968, Dover reprint) the method is defined (pag.53) for *formulae* but - if I'm not wrong - all examples that we can find in the book are made using *sentences* (i.e. closed formulae).

In Simpson's *Lectures notes* (2013), pag.31, the method is stated for *sentences*.

Is the restriction to closed formula really necessary ?

If not, how I can treat a case like :

> $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$ ?

***Added after the comments***

My answer is the following :

> due to the fact that an *open* formula $\alpha$ is *valid* iff its *universal closure* $\forall \alpha$ is

we can use the tableaux method in this way :

> check for *validity*, starting with $\lnot \forall \alpha$ : if it closes, then $\alpha$ is *valid*; if there is an open path, then $\lnot \forall \alpha$ is *satisfiable*. So also $\lnot \alpha$ is (because $\alpha$ is **not** *valid*).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux :

> The set of formulae to check for validity is here supposed to contain no free variables; this is not a limitation as free variables are implicitly universally quantified, so universal quantifiers over these variables can be added, resulting in a formula with no free variables.

Now, if we apply the method to :

> $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$

and checking it for *validity* ( i.e.starting with $\lnot \forall x [\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)]$ ), the tableau will end with $\alpha(a)$ and $\lnot \alpha(b)$. So, we can say that we have checked (what we already know) that the above formula is **not** *valid*.

Comment: I'll be watching this one. I don't understand tableaux even a little.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Volunteering to ask what?

Comment: Any attempt by me to explain the method would be taken almost directly from [these notes](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf). I believe the "tableau" of $\neg (Ax\to\forall Ax)$ is open, but I think tableaux work for closed formulae only; I'll have to revise.

Comment: About the example $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$ , the only thing I may suppose is this : if I want to test it for *vaidity*, I'll use its universal closure (because $\alpha(x)$ is valid iff $\forall x \alpha(x)$ is); if I want to test if for *satisfiability*, I'll use its existential closure (because $\alpha(x)$ is satisfiable iff $\exists x \alpha(x)$ is). Is it right ?

Comment: Not all semantics make $\alpha(x) \to (\forall x)\alpha(x)$ logically valid. I have no idea whether Smullyan's do; I know that, for example, Enderton's do not.

Comment: In Smullyan's book, pag.51, there is an *Exercise* : "show that $A(a_1)$ is valid iff $\forall x_1 A(x_1)$ is valid", where $a_1$ is a *parameter*; and the corresponding one for $\exists$. But my concern is about the "possible restriction" to the method. All examples are with *closed* formulae; so, my I apply it to *open* ones ?

Comment: I've very grateful that you asked this question, @MauroALLEGRANZA. Thank you. It looks like I have a few (hopefully not very dangerous) gaps in my understanding of the method.

Comment: If I run the method for $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$  I will obtain: *(i)* $\lnot [\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)]$ ; *(ii)* $\alpha(x)$; *(iii)* $\lnot \forall x \alpha(x)$ ; *(iv)* $\lnot \alpha(a)$. So, this square with one of my preferred examples [Shoenfield, pag.12]: what is the meaning of $x=0$? It depends on denotation we give to $x$. In the above tableau, if ve set $x := a$, the taleau will close; if we set $x := b$, it will not. This is the source of my confusion (and frustration); why both textbooks don't say: the method will work for *sentences* **only**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed at by Marc, "with *formula* Smullyan means *closed formula* as you can see on page 46".

*Sentences with parameters* are allowed (page 50) where parameters acts as *constants*.

So, we can say that the tableaux method does not apply to a formula like $P(x) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)$.

But we can apply it to a *sentence with parameters* like :

> $P(a) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)$.

In this case we have the tableau :

**F** $[ P(a) \rightarrow \forall x P(x) ]$

**T** $P(a)$

**F** $\forall x P(x)$

**F** $P(b)$ [with $b$ new].

So, the tableau does not close and the formula $\lnot ( P(a) \rightarrow \forall x P(x) )$ is *satisfiable* in a domain $U = \{ a, b \}$ where, if $P^U$ is the interpretation of the predicate $P$, we have that $a \in P^U$ and $b \notin P^U$.

This means that the formula $P(a) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)$ is **not** *valid*, because we have found a domain $U$ and an interpretation $I$ of the predicate $P$ such that the formula is **not** true under $I$ [see page 50].

This is consistent with the fact that $A(x)$ is *valid* iff $\forall x A(x)$ is [see *Exercise* on page 51].

In fact, we can start the tableau with :

> **F** $[ \forall x ( P(x) \rightarrow \forall x P(x) ) ]$

and applying *Rule D* [page 54] we get :

> **F** $[ P(a) \rightarrow \forall x P(x) ]$

From now on, the tableau will be the same as before.

In the end, we can say that the restriction to *sentences with parameters* is not a real restriction.

I think that we can remove it using formulae with free variables, taking into account that the semantics used by Smullyan is basically the same as Shoenfield (1967).

Shoenfield [page 19] says that :

> If $A$ is a formula of $L$ [a f-o language], an $\mathcal{A}$-instance of $A$ is a closed formula of the form $A[i_1, . . , i_n]$ in $L(\mathcal{A})$. A formula $A$ of $L$ is valid in $\mathcal{A}$ if $\mathcal{A}(A') = T$ for every $\mathcal{A}$-instance $A'$ of $A$" [where "we use $i$ and $j$ as syntactical variables which vary through names"].

Starting with an *open* formula $P(x) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)$, we can apply the tableaux method to its instance $P(a) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)$, and we have the same result as before.

Answer (score 2):

With *formula* Smullyan means *closed formula* as you can see on page 46.

Using tableau method you want to know whether a *formula* is true or false. But a not closed formula is neither true nor false. Now, looking at your formula $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$. It is unclear what to make of this formula. Of course, you can interpret this formula as the universally closed sentence $\forall x (\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x))$ which can be either true or false.

**Edit** Sorry for my first confusing note. Of course, you are right that many proof systems also works with formulas. I think, I just mixed up some notions. Nevertheless, I checked the Smullyan's rules again and they work for open formulas. On page 56, he also has an exercise using open formulas, e.g., $(\forall x)(Px \vee C) = (\forall x)Px \vee C)$ where $C$ is a formula where $x$ does not occur free in it.

Your question for $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$ works straightforward, since  $(\forall x)(\varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi(x)) \implies  (\forall x)\varphi(x) \rightarrow (\forall x)\psi(x)$.

However, if you want test satisfiability of $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$ you can not use the existential closure of this formula, since this means that in every structure there is an $x$ such that $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$ and not that there is a structure $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\forall x(\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x\alpha(x))$ holds in $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the definition (page 46). But I think that the method is also a *proof procedure*, and I don't think that (in general) a proof procedure must be restricted to *closed* formulae ...

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Following Carl's comment, we **know** that $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$ is **not** valid. So, if I run the method starting with $\lnot [\forall x(\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x) )]$ I will get: *(i)* $\alpha(a) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$; *(ii)* $\alpha(a)$; *(iii)* $\lnot \forall x \alpha(x)$; *(iv)* $\lnot \alpha(b)$. So, I've checked that the formula is *satisfiable* in a universe where $\alpha(a)$ holds and $\alpha(b)$ does not. So, the universal closure of $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$ is **not** *valid*

Comment: Please note Smullyan, pag.49 : "A formula $A$ is called (first order) *satisfiable* if it is true in at least one interpretation in at least one universe".

Comment: About the example on page 56, you are right. I if use only the part : $\forall x P(x) \lor C$, I'll get a single path with : $F C$ and $F P(a)$; so the tableau is finished without closing and the formula $\lnot [\forall x P(x) \lor C ]$ is *satisfiable*. I.e., $\forall x P(x) \lor C$ is **not** *valid*.

Comment: Yes, but this does not mean that you can test satisfiability using the existential closure. A formula $\varphi$ is satisfiable *iff* its universal closure $\forall \varphi$ is. A formula $\varphi$ is valid *iff* its universal closure $\forall \varphi$ is.

Comment: Tableaux is only testing for satisfiability of a formula $\varphi$. If you want to test $\varphi$ for validity, you test $\neg \varphi$ and if you want to test for satisfiability, you test $\varphi$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll try again. Starting with $\lnot[\forall x ( \alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x) )]$, the tableau will end with $\alpha(a)$ and $\lnot \alpha(b)$. So the *sentence* $\forall x (\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x))$ is not *valid* because it is *false* in an interpretation with *domain* $D= \{ a, b \}$ where $\alpha(a)$ holds and $\alpha(b)$ does not. What happens with $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$ ? 1/2

Comment: If I run the tableau with $\lnot ( \alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x) )$, it will end with $\alpha(x)$ and $\lnot \alpha(a)$. Because it is not closed, I can conclude that also the (*open*) formula $\alpha(x) \rightarrow \forall x \alpha(x)$ si not *valid*. Is my conclusion right ? 2/2

Comment: I'm not sure about your statement that : "A formula $\phi$ is satisfiable iff its universal closure $\forall \phi$ is". I assume that *satisfiable* means: "it is true in *at least* one interpretation in *at least* one universe". What about $x=0$ ? In the universe $\mathbb{N}$, if I assign $0$ to $x$ the formula is *satisfiable*. But $\forall x x = 0$ is true only in a universe with only the object $0$. Is it correct ?

Comment: But I suppose that both works. If I can find a non-empty universe where $\forall \phi$ is *true*, trivially in that universe also $\exists \phi$ is. And if I have a universe where $\exists \phi$ is true, then if I "boils down" it to the single object $x$ such that $\phi(x)$ holds (and we have at least one $x$ such that ...) , I will get a new universe where $\forall \phi$ is true.

Comment: But I'm not sure that the above argument is correct. Instaed, I can refer to Mendelson, *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (4th ed, 1997), pag.67, Ex.2.20 : "Prove that, if the free variables of $B$ are $y_1, ... y_n$, then $B$ is satisfiable iff $(\exists y_1) ... (\exists y_n) B$ is satisfiable".